# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 (bindvalue as integer)

Tags: php, mysql

When I try to compere the value of my `(int) user id from $_SESSION['user']['id']` with this code:

```
$userId = '';
if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
$userId = $_SESSION['user']['id']; //56) uitlezen van de sessievariabele...

// TODO: 57) statement voor een select uit te voeren... user en deleted...
$sql_notes_select_where
    = 'SELECT '
    . '`note_id` AS `id`,'
    . '`note_title` AS `title`,'
    . '`note_content` AS `content`'
    . 'FROM `notes` '
    . 'WHERE '
    .       '`note_deleted` is null and'
    .       '`user_id`=:userid'
;


try {
    // 58) Connectie openen met db...
    $db = getDbConnection();
    /**
     * Zie ook: http://courses.olivierparent.be/php/databases/pdo-php-data-objects/
     */
    if ($stmt_notes_select_where = $db->prepare($sql_notes_select_where)) {
        // TODO: 59) Binding uitvoeren user...
        $stmt_notes_select_where->bindValue(':userid', $userId);
        $stmt_notes_select_where->execute();
    }
    // TODO: 60) Het opvragen van het aantal rijen...
    //$results = ...;
    $results = $db->query($sql_notes_select_where);


    // 61) Het sluiten van de connectie met de db.
    closeDbConnection($db);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    switch ($e->getCode()) {
        case '23000':
            $error = "Er bestaat al een gebruiker met <strong>{$_POST['email']}</strong> als e-mailadres.";
            break;
        default:
            $error = 'Er is een fout gebeurd: ' . $e->getMessage();
            break;
    }
}
```

I get this error message.

> *Er is een fout gebeurd: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access
>   violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to
>   use near ':userid' at line 1*

Comment: you are missing space...

Comment: Where am I missing space?

Answer (score 0):

What the query returns to you when executing it in MySQL ? Does your columns datatype is same as th value you want to bind it with ?

Try the following:

```
SELECT note_id AS `id`,
    note_title AS `title`,
    note_content AS `content`
    FROM `notes` 
    WHERE 
   note_deleted is null and
    user_id= :userid
;
```

**EDIT**
Set 2 session variables, the first is `$_SESSION['user']` and the second is `$_SESSION['id of your user']` when logging in.

```
<?php
$DB_host = "localhost";
$DB_user = "your user";
$DB_pass = "your pass";
$DB_name = "your database";
//try to put the id in the session
//Then
$userId = $_SESSION['id'];
 $conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$DB_host};dbname={$DB_name}",$DB_user,$DB_pass);
         $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
?>
    <body>
    <?php 
            $selectAll = "SELECT note_id AS id,
        note_title AS title,
        note_content AS content
        FROM notes 
        WHERE 
       note_deleted is null and
        user_id= :id";
            $stmtAll=$conn->prepare($selectAll);
            $stmtAll->bindValue(':id', $userId);
            $execAll=$stmtAll->execute();
            $result=$stmtAll->fetchAll(); 
            foreach($result as $rows){
              var_Dump($rows) ?>
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td>
    <?php       echo $rows['title'];
    ?>
    </td>
```

And this is my result (it works):

[image]

Comment: Now the error says  "Er is een fout gebeurd: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '` is null and user_id= '1'' at line 1"

Comment: try it in mysql but instead of ='1' try  =1

Comment: What is your columns datatype ? Please provide to us some info about your mysql table

Comment: that's when it works. It seams like he gets the :userid as a string since it has been declared as a (int) in the session

Comment: your note_deleted is timestamp ?

Comment: yes, it's a "soft delete" so it registers when you delete a note and give it a timestamp. When the value of delete is null it will be displayed. I know it's kinda crapy but it's a school project with partial given code

Comment: Okay wait, I am testing

Comment: I appreciate this a lot!!

Answer (score 0):

It was a stupid mistake. It's fixed by setting  `$results = $stmt_notes_select_where`
That was it.